# Unable to understand pthread_create() behaviour in the following program?

Tags: c, linux, unix, pthreads

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *thread_func(void *arg)
{
        printf("hello, world \n");
        return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
        pthread_t t1, t2;

        pthread_create(&t1, NULL, thread_func, NULL);
        pthread_create(&t2, NULL, thread_func, NULL);

        printf("t1 = %d\n",t1);
        printf("t2 = %d\n",t2);

        return 0;
}
```

The above program creates two threads, where each thread prints "Hello World".

So, as per my understanding, the "Hello world" should print a maximum 2 times.

However, **while executing the same program multiple times**(back to back), there are scenarios where "Hello world" is being printed **more** than **2** times. So I am unclear how it is getting printed an unexpected number of times?

Here are the sample outputs:

```
[rr@ar ~]$ ./a.out
t1 = 1290651392
t2 = 1282258688
hello, world
hello, world


[rr@ar ~]$ ./a.out
t1 = 1530119936
t2 = 1521727232
hello, world
hello, world
hello, world
```

As shown above, after executing the program for many times, **"hello, world"** is printed **3** times. Can anyone please advise **how come it got printed 3 times?**

Comment: The program code shown in the question is not the code of the program that produced the output you show in the question.  That makes it impossible for us to answer your question.  Get the code and output consistent before asking questions (or giving answers).  Also note that the thread functions are supposed to return a `void *` value — add `return 0;`.  You don't wait for the threads to complete; that may be a factor in the problem, though I reserve judgement on that.

Comment: Thanks  Jonathan Leffler , i have corrected my Question. still i am getting the same output as posted earlier.

Comment: Your program is probably terminating before the threads are done,Abnormal termination of program may lead to such behavior, you should call pthread_join for both threads prior to returning from main

Comment: Nope nos, I haven't run a code other than the one i posted. thanks!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I cannot guess how do you deduct that the program listing is not the same as the program producing the output.  Can you explain?

Comment: @LuisColorado: the code presented was edited after I pointed out the problem. If you look at the revision history, you'll see that the output always said `t1 = …` but the code did not, for example.

Comment: People need to read the specification of POSIX [`flockfile()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/flockfile.html)
and `funlockfile()`.  That page says: _All functions that reference (`FILE *`) objects, except those with names ending in `_unlocked`, shall behave as if they use `flockfile()` and `funlockfile()` internally to obtain ownership of these (`FILE *`) objects._  Thus, if thread 1 is executing `printf()`, all other threads are locked out from accessing `stdout` until thread 1's call is effectively complete (it has called `funlockfile(stdout)`).

Answer (score 4):

You experienced a thread-safety problem. I ran your code several times in Linux 16.04 and it produces many different outputs, while the one with 3 `hello world` message being rare it exists. More frequently there is no output at all which means that `main` terminates faster than threads being able to finish their outputs. Sometime partial outputs are produced like:

```
t1=xxxx
t2=yyyy
he
```

That means that the `main` is exiting while only one thread was able to push some characters in the stdout buffer. Remember that a normal return from `main` is equivalent to a call to `exit` which flushes stdio buffers.

While I am unable to really understand what happens behind the scene when you observe 3 messages, I suspect that there exists a run race that let the `main` flushing a buffer that is currently being flush by one of the threads. Without examining very carefully the source code of `printf` it is very hard to say more. A possible (rough) scenario would looks like:

1. thread1 fills the buffers and enters the flushing but is preempted at the very beginning of it
2. main exits, so enters the flushing and terminates it and is preempted at the very end of it thus producing `hello world`
3. thread1 finishes its flushing producing `hello world`
4. thread2 produces `hello world`
5. main gets the CPU and terminates the process.

`printf` is not defined as thread-safe, which means that implementors may realize it as such or not (probably not in most cases). So you need, as with any function that uses some shared resource, some mutex to prevents buffer concurrency and such.

In your case, this should be roughly solved (3 outputs) by joining the threads in the main which will prevent `main` exiting/flushing before threads termination. But be aware that this will not solve other concurrency problems (two threads accessing the same buffer...).

Comment: Jean-Baptiste, I'm afraid the three messages case is also not covered by your solution and he will have to protect the `FILE` instance with a `mutex` or similar protection.  See my answer, as it illustrates one possibility of such a race, involving _only_ the two threads, and not considering the _atexit_ flushing of `stdout` made by `main`.

Comment: @LuisColoradoYour explanation is almost the same of mine. And 3 messages are easy to generate as the second thread just needs to run after main flushed everything but not closed stdout...

Answer (score 2):

Well, let me show an scenario where this can happen.  You probably know (if you don't, please read the appropiate manual page) that `printf()` is one of the functions that is not thread safe of the standard library (there is a list in the `pthread_<something>`, somewhere) and you probably also know that `printf(3)` stores its data in a buffer previously to issue the `write(2)` system call to actually write the data to stdout.

1. Thread A (I deliverately selected different labels as you, to make both threads indistinguishable, so Thread A can be either thread) makes a `printf()` call that puts a compllete `"Hello, world\n"` message in the buffer, and prepares to `write(2)` it, as a consequence of the terminal being a **tty** device and a `\n` ends the output string.
2. Thread B takes control and makes a second call to the same `printf(2)`data (and fills the same buffer with a second copy of `"Hello, world\n"`) and for the same reason, prepares and completely executes a `write(2)` syscall of the whole buffer (which now contains two messages) flushes the buffer.  this makes `"Hello, world\n"` to appear twice.
3. Thread A, which has been blocked by means of the first `write(2)` system call (both threads cannot make simultaneous `write(2)` calls to the same inode ---this is warranted by the system kernel) flushes **it's view** (which probably is stored in its stack, and includes only the reference to the first message) of the buffer (which finished at the end of the first `"Hello, world\n"`) and makes another write of one more `"Hellow, world\n"` message)

Final score: Three `"Hellow, world\n"` messages at the terminal.

## NOTE

The most probable thing is that getting three messages is difficult to happen, as you need one of the threads to bypass the other in the time `printf` decides it is time to flush the buffer, after filling it (which is a short time) and then get first into the blocking `write(2)` call (as explained before, both threads cannot be involved in a `write(2)` call at the same time to the same file, that's not permitted by the kernel)

Comment: It sometimes prints "hello, world" 4 times also.

Comment: Manual page of `pthreads` claims that `printf` shall be thread safe. On the other hand `printf` is not reentrant, i.e. it shall not be interrupted and re-called for the second time in the same thread. This is probably what happens in this example when the main program aborts subthreads.

Comment: @Marian, sorry, but reentrancy is a pre-requisite for a call to be thread safe.  You have to protect the buffer used in the FILE structure.  reentrancy or thread safety of `printf` is a design decision of `printf` itself.  It depends on the implementation of `printf` to want to be compatible with the implementation of the thread library.  Pthreads library cannot argue that some other routine not implemented in the pthread library **is** implemented as such, It can **require** `printf` to be thread safe, but cannot say that something implemented elsewhere **is** something.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès When I type `man pthreads` I see: "POSIX.1-2001 and POSIX.1-2008 require that all functions specified in the standard shall be thread-safe, except for the following functions:" followed by a list of function where `printf` is not listed.

Comment: @Marian right I misread the manual. Then Linux is not POSIX compliant...

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Or it is caused by `exit` which is not thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

When the main program terminates sub threads are terminated as well.

It can happen that both sub-threads are executed before the main task finishes. In this case you see two "hello worlds" and the output as you show in the question.

Also it can happen that the main program finishes before one or both threads print the output. In this case you can see one or no "hello world" at all.

I do not see any possibility that a single run of this program prints it 3 times. I suppose that you are executing the program in a loop and the output of two runs is mixed together. ADDED: For example, imagine the following scenario: RUN1: prints two numbers, then subthreads are scheduled and they print one "hello world" each, then RUN1 main is scheduled back and program finishes. Next, RUN2 is launched. In this case both subthreads are scheduled before the main program prints the numbers.

So you see an output like:

```
t1=346236763               (RUN1 - main)
t2=876237623               (RUN1 - main)
hello, world               (RUN1 - subthread)
hello, world               (RUN1 - subthread)
hello, world               (RUN2 - subthread)
hello, world               (RUN2 - subthread)
t1=3786768623              (RUN2 - main)
t2=7843473478              (RUN2 - main)
```

the output can be wrongly interpreted as if there were 4 "hello worlds" written by a single run.

Comment: Hi Marian I agree with your 1st & 2nd points. And YES I am executing ./a.out  multiiple times , but I am unable to understand how come the outputs get mixed if i execute same program again and again.

Comment: Your scenario does not include the command line ./a.out for RUN2 which should be visible between the output of RUN1 and RUN2.

Comment: @Gerhardh Because printf shall be thread-safe, I guess that the supposed 3 "hello worlds" are due to a human misunderstanding of the output. It is on OP to say, if this was the case or not.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès according to the example in the question, it is not `a.out; a.out` but separate commands with the second entered after first exited.

Comment: @Gerhardh As pointed in comments, samples shown in the question are not authentic.

Comment: @Marian outputs are real, I experienced them very easily.